# Tab bar vanishes from a viewController when returned to via a segue - swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, tabbar

I have an application that uses a tab bar.  I have a custom camera view assigned to one tab.  When an image is captured , I get a preview of it in another view controller.  When I hit a custom back button - by using a segue-  I go back to the custom camera view.  However, I then cannot see the tab bar?  Please can some one advise?

This is the link to my storyboard: [Storyboard](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s2D2yaWlTSXk-Ltqcd69JWHs0Od0mD07/view?usp=sharing)

Image capture:

```
 // Preview cropped image in another vC
      if let unwrpCroppedImg = croppedImg{
      self.croppedImage = unwrpCroppedImg
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segPreview", sender: nil)
 }


 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "segPreview"{
        let previewVC = segue.destination as! PreviewImageViewController
        previewVC.prevImage = self.croppedImage
    }

}
```

Back Button

```
 @IBAction func cancelCapture(_ sender: Any) {
    // Go back to image capture
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segCancelImage", sender: nil)

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe try `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` instead of segue in `cancelCapture()`.

Comment: How do you switch from camera to image preview?

Comment: @mag_zbc please see update

Comment: You are showing a new instance of your view controller. You need to use an [unwid segue](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2298/_index.html)

Comment: @Paulw11 if you would like to add this as an answer i can accept it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may Helps You

- Remove Segue imageViewController to camera screen.

  ```
  @IBAction func cancelCapture(_ sender: Any) {

     self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
     //self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) //If push type navigation.
  }
  ```

Comment: Won't this only work if the viewcontroller you're trying to dismiss has been presented? It totally depends of the kind of segue used, I mean.